TMC Beans shows no project found
I am currently learning java through the MOOC course and i started to face an issue where TMC beans displays  even though
I already have the projects downloaded. To provide more context, I had downloaded java-17 a couple days ago and since then it has stopped working even after i removed it from my system. I really want to continue the course what do I do
I have tried all the guides and uninstalled TMC beans and reinstalled it but it still doesn't work T.T

"downloaded java-17" - Maybe install (or re-install) Java 11 instead? Research similar questions, such as TMCbeans does not open after installation - and plenty of others. Have you also (re-)reviewed and followed the installation guide?

"i removed it from my system" - depends on what that means, if it did what you need. "tried all the guides" - that is quite vague...

Hello Despair, "Windows" or "Linux"?.

i am on windows
